# grep till end of quote

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a sample textfile(test_long_sentence.txt) below and I want to grep all the lines that contain test1 excluding unwanted data.

How do I grep the data before the quote closes?

test_long_sentence.txt

```
This is some unwanted data blah blah blah

20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"

This is some unwanted data blah blah blah

20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

Command:

```
grep "test1" test_long_sentence.txt
```

Actual Output:

```
20  /test1/catergory="food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

Expected Output:

```
20  /test1/catergory="food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

Ps: I have no control in editing the test_long_sentence.txt. So please, do not ask me to edit it to a single line.

Comment: you don't have to edit the input file, but you will have to at least pre-process it (e.g. with an awk or perl script) to join lines that don't start with a number and a space (that seems to be the common factor in continued lines from the small sample you've given).  the pre-processing script will also have to ignore all lines from an empty line to the next line starting with a number.   BTW, since you'll need perl or awk or similar to join the continued lines, you may as well make it also do the search & print.

Comment: Is `pcregrep` an option? e.g. `pcregrep -M '(?s)test1.*?"\n' test_long_sentence.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using awk

```
$ awk '/test1/{line=$0; while (!(line ~ /[^\\]".*[^\\]"/)) {getline; line=line "\n" $0}; print line}' sentence.txt 
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

`/test1/` is a condition.  If the current line contains a match to the regex `test1`, then the commands in curly braces are performed.  Those commands are:

- `line=$0`

  The contents of the current line are saved in variable `line.
- `while (!(line ~ !/[^\\]".*[^\\]"/)) {getline; line=line "\n" $0}`

  If the current contents of `line` do not contain two unescaped quotes, then get the next line, `getline` and append it to `line` via `line=line "\n" $0`
- `print line`

  Now that the variable `line` contains two unescaped quotes, we print it.

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines, the same command as above can be written as:

```
awk '
    /test1/{
        line=$0
        while (!(line ~ /[^\\]".*[^\\]"/)) {
            getline
            line=line "\n" $0
        }
        print line
    }' sentence.txt
```

## Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/test1/{:a; /[^\\]".*[^\\]"/{p;b}; N; ba}' sentence.txt 
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

**How it works:**

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/test1/{...}`

  For any line containing `test1`, we perform the commands in curly braces which are:

  - `:a`

    This defines a label `a`.
  - `/[^\\]".*[^\\]"/{p;b}`

    If the pattern space currently contains two unescaped quotes, we print the pattern space, `p`, and then we skip the rest of the instructions and branch, `b`, to start over on the next line.
  - `N`

    If we get here, that means that the current did not have two unescaped quotes.  We read in the next line into the pattern space.
  - `ba`

    We branch back to label `a` and repeat that commands which follow that label.

Comment: Thanks! Using sed method worked! I edited it a bit to accept variable input:  sed -n '/$var/{:a; /[^\\]".*[^\\]"/{p;b}; N; ba}' sentence.txt. But I am curious to know how will the var work if I am using awk method?

Comment: @Jojoleo To use the awk method with a variable: `awk -v x="test1" '$0~x{line=$0; while (!(line ~ /[^\\]".*[^\\]"/)) {getline; line=line "\n" $0}; print line}' sentence.txt`.  If you are going to use a variable, the awk method is actually safer than sed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with `awk` instead of `grep` for that particular file:

```
awk 'NR==3,NR==7;NR==11' test_long_sentence.txt
```

To help with this in the future, you can run `cat -n` on the file to see the lines that you want to include and exclude.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple perl script to join the continued lines in your input.  It assumes:

- continued lines are to be joined with a single space character.
- a "line" starts from any input line beginning with a number and a space, and continues until either:

  - a blank like
  - another line beginning with a number and a space
- blank lines, and all lines between blank lines are to be ignored (i.e. discarded).

This may not be a perfect match for your actual input file, but does match the sample input provided in your question.  Modify the code to suit your input as required.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $skip=1;  # start with skip = true.
my $line='';

while(<>) {
  chomp;

  if (m/^\d+\s+/) { # / this comment is only here to fix SE\'s syntax highlighting
    $skip=0;
    print $line,"\n" if ($line);
    $line = $_;

 } elsif (m/^\s*$/) {
    if ($line ne '') { print $line, "\n"; $line = ''};
    $skip = 1 - $skip;

  } elsif (! $skip) {
    $line .= " $_";
 };
};
```

save as, e.g., `./join-lines.pl`, make executable with `chmod +x ./join-lines.pl`, and run like:

```
$ ./join-lines.pl test_long_sentence.txt 
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly, Babies, \"Witch\", Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/theme="Halloween"
```

This can then be fed into `grep` or other tools as required.

Note that with the current sample input, the output of `./join-lines.pl test_long_sentence.txt | grep test1` is (apart from possible colourisation of matches by `grep`) identical to the output above because all of the sample lines contain "test1".  You can more usefully grep for other matches, e.g.:

```
$ ./join-lines.pl test_long_sentence.txt | grep Witch
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly, Babies, \"Witch\", Faries"
```

---

If you need to be able to reproduce the exact same input (but without the blank and unwanted lines) then instead of joining the lines with a space, use a character (e.g. a TAB) or a longer string (e.g. `" ===NL=== "`) that you are absolutely certain will never appear in the input.  e.g.

```
  } elsif (! $skip) {
    $line .= "\t$_";
 };
```

or

```
  } elsif (! $skip) {
    $line .= " ===NL=== $_ ";
 };
```

The joining string can then be converted back to a newline with, e.g., `sed` (using a tab character as the join character):

```
$ ./join-lines.pl test_long_sentence.txt  | grep Witch | sed -e 's/\t/\n/g'
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
```

Another example, using a longer string for joining the lines:

```
./join-lines.pl test_long_sentence.txt  | grep Witch | sed -e 's/ ===NL=== /\n/g'
```