# multiple patterns with sed (regex AND or condition)

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I want to remove the unwanted data.
So my question is how do I delete lines above test1 if it does not contain test1 **OR** not ended with a quote?

```
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
**This is some unwanted data to remove**
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/end=category
**This is some unwanted data to remove**
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create 
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
```

**Expected output:**

```
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/end=category
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create 
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
```

I was stuck with these few commands :

```
1. grep -B1 'test1' test_long_sentence.txt
2. sed '/test1/!d' test_long_sentence.txt 
3. sed '/\"$/!d' test_long_sentence.txt
```

I do not know how to combine no. 2 and 3 (sed with multiple commands with regex and OR condition)

Comment: Do you mean `sed '/test1/!d; /\"$/!d' test_long_sentence.txt ` ?

Comment: Hmm i did tried that as well but i was left with lines that consist of test1 **and** ends with quote @GillesQuenot

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: The problem is that you have annoyingly-formatted input data that's difficult to work with using standard line-oriented text-processing tools.  The best (i.e. least hassle) option in situations like this is to convert it to some less annoying, easy-to-work-with format.  and optionally convert it back to the original format afterwards.  This allows you to use any of the standard tools as normal. 
 See my [updated answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423512/7696) to your related question for an example of how to do this.

Comment: @cas sorry but the input data are not generated by me and I wish they were less annoyingly-formatted. I am currently using a script to run the input data already and I doubt I can edit the input format as I have to return them to their original state but removing the unwanted data only. I appreciate your answer and I will see what I can do with it. :) Thanks

Comment: @GillesQuenot have updated it above.

Comment: I am aware that the input data is not generated by you.  Having to work with annoyingly formatted data provided by others is, unfortunately, an extremely common problem.   Common problems have common solutions, and converting to and from annoying formats to less- or non- annoying formats is a common solution.   Did you not read my comment - it specifically stated "**... convert it back to the original format afterwards**".

Comment: If that makes no sense to you, here's a real-world analogy: you have hundreds of tiny little things to move from one room to another.  You **could** move them all individually.  But that's annoying and would take ages.  Alternatively, you could convert them into one object by putting them all into a box, move that one box, and then convert back to hundreds of tiny objects by unpacking the box.

Comment: @GillesQuenot slightly tweaked: `sed -n '/test1/p; /",\?$/p'` (the `,\?` allows for lines that end in a quote *followed by a trailing comma*, which the OP doesn't explicitly mention but appear in the desired output)

Comment: Isn't this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423541/delete-line-after-keyword1-if-keyword2-does-not-exist a similar question asked by you yesterday?

Comment: @Inian seems like but my question now includes OR condition and regex in sed

Comment: Well, the OR condition in a sed regex is expressed with `|` - so to answer your question *as posted*, `sed -n '/test1\|"$/p'` however based on your desired output you seem to want to allow for an optional trailing comma *after* the quote, i.e. `sed -n '/test1\|",\?$/p'`. I'd expect this to be a fragile solution though since it's based on lexical appearance rather than structure.

Answer (score 5):

`lex` (or `flex` on Linux systems) is a program that takes a scanner/lexer specification and turns it into a C program.  Its scanner specification is similar in nature to an `awk` program, but where `awk` is record oriented `lex` is "character oriented".

Using `lex` with the following source in `lexer.l`:

```
%x OUTPUT
%%
                        int quoted = 0;

^[0-9]*[ \t]*"/test1/"  { BEGIN OUTPUT;             ECHO; }
<OUTPUT>\n              { if (!quoted) { BEGIN 0; } ECHO; }
<OUTPUT>[^\\]["]        { quoted = !quoted;         ECHO; }
<OUTPUT>.               {                           ECHO; }
.|\n                    ;
```

This scanner uses an `OUTPUT` state to keep track of whether we want the current characters outputted or not.  We enter this state with `BEGIN OUTPUT` when we find a line that looks like

```
<number>  /test1/
```

(this is handled by the first rule). We exit this state when a line ends and we're not currently scanning a quoted string (this is handled by the second rule).

A quoted string is started and ended with an un-escaped `"` character (the third rule).  All other characters are passed through as is without action (the fourth rule).

While not in the `OUTPUT` state, we ignore everything (the last rule).

Note that this is a makeshift scanner written for your particular data. It does not handle quoted strings that ends with an escaped backslash (`"some data \\"`), but it works on the data that you have shown.

Building it:

```
$ make lexer
lex  -o lex.lexer.c lexer.l
cc -O2 -pipe    -o lexer lex.lexer.c  -ll
rm -f lex.lexer.c
```

(on Linux, when using `flex`, you may have to use `make lexer LDLIBS=-ll`)

Using it:

```
$ ./lexer <file
20  /test1/catergory="Food"
20  /test1/target="Adults, \"Goblins\", Elderly,
Babies, \"Witch\",
Faries"
20  /test1/type="Western"
20  /test1/end=category
20  /test1/Purpose=
20  /test1/my_purpose="To create
a fun-filled moment"
20  /test1/end=Purpose
```